# How to connect 3 forms into one

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, c#-4.0

I am with a problem where I have 3 forms and a class called Languages. The 3 Forms are the Main Form, The Settings Form and Languages Form. So what I need help with is, when I click in the language flag, I am trying to access to Main Form to pick up there a function I created there called 'changedLanguages()' I can access it, but when I click the flag, the Main Form is not Updating the changes without close the actual opened Main Form. But if i write a line of code `mus.Show();` it opens a new one with the changes. 
But I want to do the changes in the actual opened Main Form. Is it possible?

Below you have the LanguagesForm from the flag image click:

```
 private void ptLang_img_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        enLang_img.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        ptLang_img.BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;

        Form1 mus = new Form1();
        Languages PT_lang = new Languages();
        mus.changeLanguage(PT_lang.file_PT, PT_lang.open_PT, PT_lang.settings_PT, PT_lang.exit_PT, PT_lang.controls_PT, PT_lang.play_PT, PT_lang.pause_PT, PT_lang.stop_PT, PT_lang.next_PT, PT_lang.prev_PT, PT_lang.playRecently_PT, PT_lang.volUp_PT, PT_lang.volDown_PT, PT_lang.help_PT, PT_lang.about_PT, PT_lang.faq_PT, PT_lang.update_PT);
        mus.Refresh();
    }
```

And here you have the function of 'changedLanguages()':

```
public void changeLanguage(string file, string open, string settings, string exit, string controls, string play, string pause, string stop, string next, string prev, string recPlayed, string volUp, string volDown, string help, string about, string faq, string update)
    {
        fileToolStripMenuItem.Text = file;
        openToolStripMenuItem.Text = open;
        settingsToolStripMenuItem.Text = settings;
        exitToolStripMenuItem.Text = exit;
        controlsToolStripMenuItem.Text = controls;
        playToolStripMenuItem.Text = play;
        pauseToolStripMenuItem.Text = pause;
        stopToolStripMenuItem.Text = stop;
        forwardToolStripMenuItem.Text = next;
        backwardToolStripMenuItem.Text = prev;
        playRecentToolStripMenuItem.Text = recPlayed;
        volumeUpToolStripMenuItem.Text = volUp;
        volumeDownToolStripMenuItem.Text = volDown;
        helpToolStripMenuItem.Text = help;
        aboutUMusicToolStripMenuItem.Text = about;
        fAQToolStripMenuItem.Text = faq;
        updatesToolStripMenuItem.Text = update;
    }
```

Any help is welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a static instance of your main form, I hope that the changes will be immediately visible, if it does not work, add this statement after making your changes

`Application.DoEvents();`

Comment: I forgot to mention something sorry... LanguageForm is a child of Settings Form